Block altering, moving, or uninstalling apps
I have an Oppo A53 phone, and I want my kid not to alter, move, or uninstall apps. Is there a way to deactivate the clicking and dragging of apps with some sort of script? I don't want to hide apps, I want the pages to be like JPEG, not an Object.
I didn't try creating a new user yet due to storage "working on it"; also I didn't try hiding apps because I don't want it.

It would probably be easiest to create a new user for him. If you're concerned about storage, you can create a temporary guest user and then delete it when he's done using it.
See this android help article for information about how to create a new user: https://support.google.com/android/answer/2865483
If you would like more information about guest users, see this article:
https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/6115141
